# What's the difference between mx: and include: in SPF records?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

I'm very new to all things DNS, yet I am trying to set up some SPF records. So far the [SPF Setup Wizard](http://old.openspf.org/wizard.html) has been immensely helpful, and I think I have things pretty much set; however I'd really like to know what the difference between `mx:domain.com` and `include:domain.com` is. Is it somewhat redundant to have both? Or do they both do mutually exclusive things? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- "include:" includes the settings from another SPF-record (must point to a different name) - it does not actually specify any hosts ifself.
- "mx:" includes the hosts designated by MX-records for a domain name (same a using "a:" for each of the host names pointed to by the MX-records).

Answer (score 3):

The 'include' directive allows you to import SPF settings from another zone.  Imagine if you are a company that has 5-7 zone.  Rather than writing the SPF records each time, you can just write them on one and import to the others.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Helped me! This seems to be a primary use-case (along with "I need to import someone else's SPF") of include. Kind of wish the syntax docs mentioned this more explicitly as a distinguishing reason to use include rather than "a".